# TextInputLayout multiline hint?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I would like to create an EditText look like below image using android native `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`.

More clearly the hint should be show in multi line.

[image]

I've tried adding escape character `\n` in `string.xml` like

`<string name="mobile_comp">Mobile Number \n (For chat...)</string>`

It seems doesn't work when i place `EditText` inside `TextInputLayout`.So any one know what's I'm doing wrong here ? I surfed but couldn't find the reason ?

**Code**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/text_input_margin"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_input_margin">

                            <com.ribbnapp.ribbn.views.EditText
                                android:id="@+id/mobile"
                                style="@style/EditText"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_height"
                                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_mobile_number2"
                                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/drawable_padding"
                                android:hint="@string/mobile_comp"
                                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                                android:inputType="phone"
                                android:maxLength="10"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />
                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**Gradle dependencies**

```
 // App common
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar"
    // Facebook SDK
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
```

Comment: I have tried it but couldn't make it work.can the duplicate marker of my query can explain the reason..???????????????? :(

Comment: And currently am using v23 support libraries .but still the problem remains.@Lakhan see my edited query.

Comment: Your string is "country_comp" but why you use android:hint="@string/mobile_comp"

Comment: @Danh DC typing error. see my edit.

Comment: Your custom edittext have display Hint text, or just show blank

Comment: Please post answer to the query if u know :)

Comment: Please check your EditText height and padding, maybe it too small to display text